# why does the answer to that question like that !!?

Tags: probability

A manufacturer of a flu vaccine is concerned

about the quality of its flu serum. Batches of serum are

processed by three different departments having rejection rates of 0.10, 0.08,

and 0.12, respectively.

The inspections by the three departments are sequential 
and independent.

(a) What is the probability that a batch of serum survives the first 
departmental inspection but is rejected by the second department?

(b) What is the probability that a batch of serum is

rejected by the third department?

My question is :

here he says that the department have a rejection rate

does this differ from saying 
that the serum have a rejection rate with a value x  for department y ?

and for the point number (B) in my book he answer it as(.90*.92*.12)

why it`s not just (.12 )

and how he come with this answer and if it`s not right to be (.12) so what is the difference between the meaning of the syntax given in the above question and that says that the rejection rate for 3rd company is .12 and the meaning of the syntax in the point (b)

thanks in advance

Comment: See [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for how to improve the formatting of your post using MarkDown. A pretty post will be better received here.

Comment: This is a poorly phrased problem...if nothing else, one would like to imagine that the screening departments are actually able to spot flaws in the serum (in which case it doesn't make sense to say that the three screens are independent).  Still, sticking with that unphysical assumption, it is presumably implied that, in order for the third department to block it, the serum must have cleared the first two (else it wouldn't even make it to the third).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the rejection rate for each department is that if you give the first department $100$ samples they will accept $90$ and reject $10$ of them.  When the problem says the inspections are independent it means that the ones accepted by the first department are no more likely to be rejected by the second department than the rejected ones would be.  When the inspections are sequential, we discard the rejected ones at each step.  For b, we are asked the chance a sample that has not yet been tested by anybody is rejected by the third department.  To be rejected by the third department it must pass the first two, otherwise the third department never sees it.  That is where the factors $0.90$ and $0.92$ come from.

Comment: why we discard the rejected once couldn't we have  an example of( R  , AC , R) where R mean rejected and AC mean Accepted and  the example is for each department from 1 to 3rd sequentially why we can`t encounter example like that if we can't what is the part of the question that till us about that

Comment: Because if the first department rejects it, the others never see it.

Comment: why that logic is exist ? does the word sequentially implies on what you say or what ?? my saying is it`s normal to keep the process and test the sample even if it was rejected by the previous one

Comment: I read sequentially to mean the sample is discarded after any rejection.

Comment: can you refer me any thing that say so like ( a book , or Wikipedia ) or any thing that talk about events that are sequential

Comment: I would see that as English, not math.  If the first department rejects it, why would you bother to pass it to the second department?  Of course, in that case we don't really know the rejections are independent.  What we know is the rejection rate of the second department for the items they receive, which are the ones the first department passed.

Comment: okay thanks for answering me